# How is this CoreData fetch in swift 3?

Tags: core-data, swift2, swift3, fetch

This is a fetch, which will bring me the data of a specific entity, but in swift 2 and i need it in swift 3..

```
func fetchProfile(){
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Perfil")
    do {
        let result = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        for managedObject in result {
            if let name = managedObject.valueForKey("name")
            {
                oProfile.oProfile_Name = (name as! String)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print(fetchError)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 3 `NSFetchRequest` is a generic type

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Perfil")
do {
     let result = try moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject] 
...
```

To take advantage of the generic type it's highly recommended to use `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

Comment: `moc` is the current `NSManagedObjectContext` instance.